# Validate Binomial distribution exercise with pullets and cockerels

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution

The exercise is as follows:

> The owner of chicken farm knows, that the event of hatching out a cockerel is three time more frequent than a pullet.
>   One should count the probability, that from five random selected eggs there will hatch out at least one cockerel.

My answer is:

random variable X - the count of hatched out cockerels

success - hatching out of cockerel

$p = \frac{3}{4}, q=\frac{1}{4}, n=5\\
P(X=x) = \binom{n}{x} \cdot p^{x} \cdot q^{n-x}\\
P(X  \ge 1)=1-P(X=0)\\ 
P(X=0)=\binom{5}{0} \cdot \left( \frac{3}{4}\right) ^0 \cdot \left( \frac{1}{4}\right) ^5 \approx 0.001\\
P(X \ge 1) = 1- 0,001 = 0,999$

Please validate my answer.

Comment: Looks good. Nothing to add.

Comment: Mixing notation 0.001 & 0,001.

Comment: Alright, so no way the real answer for this example would be $0.75$? That's the answer which is shown in answers. That's why I've posted this question.

Comment: I don't see how.